# Filter a field with timestamp (datetime) to get rows that does not contain today's date in Django

Tags: filter, django-rest-framework

I have a Django model with a timestamp field. I want to filter and get the number of rows that does not contain today's date. The timestamp field contains the date, time, and time zone.

I understand that to get rows with today's date, we do the following:

```
tablename.objects.filter(timestamp__date=date.today()).count()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.exclude` returns the inverse of `.filter`, so it would be

```
tablename.objects.exclude(timestamp__date=date.today()).count()
```

Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#exclude)